# what is wrong with write(java.nio.Buffer), JDK cannot resolve Buffer inside write

Tags: java

this syntax gets a compile-time error:

`serverSocket.write( ByteBuffer.allocate(34).put( "Hello".getBytes("UTF-8") ).flip() );`

cannot resolve method `write(java.nio.Buffer)`

while `flip()` returns *this Buffer*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except that `flip()` indeeds return a `Buffer`, but not a `ByteBuffer`.

[And the method you try to use needs a `ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#write-java.nio.ByteBuffer-). `ByteBuffer` extends `Buffer`, but not every `Buffer` is a `ByteBuffer`.

[side note: never use `.getBytes()` on a `String` directly; always specify the encoding]

Comment: yes I just saw that but its doc is somehow misleading, it says the buffer from which bytes are to be retrieved, and you mean this buffer is not exactly the Buffer that extends ByteBuffer?

Comment: It will be the same (otherwise the contract would be violated); however you have to obey the method prototype :) Sure, you could cast, but then adding one or two lines of code is all that is required to fix the problem -- and you end up with more readable code